# Globally changing matplotlib default styles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question: how can I use a default style on matplotlib (because I like it) but change only a single parameter? Here's an example:
using the default matplotlib style or the "calssic" one I can change the font size globally by updating rcParams:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18.0})

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 1, 4, 9]

fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax0.plot(x, y)
ax0.set_xlabel('data x')
ax0.set_ylabel('data y')
plt.show()
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Mkk.png)

if instead I choose a different default style at the beginning:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18.0})

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 1, 4, 9]

fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax0.plot(x, y)
ax0.set_xlabel('data x')
ax0.set_ylabel('data y')
plt.show()
```

[the font size remains of the default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjzYr.png)
it doesn't work like that;

```
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18.0})
```

It's like the `font.size` line doesn't exist.
Now a simple solution to this would be to define a global variable with a specific font size and manually add it to every element of the plot but it doesn't sound that clever to me. Any other ideas how to modify the fontsize globally? Is it in fact possible or do I just have to deal with it and create a matplotlib style file on my own?

EDIT:
By a more careful thought, following DavidG comment, I tried with different styles: ggplot and fivethirtyeight even seaborn-dark, and my code works (as I would expect). The issue is then related to the seaborn style only (that I am being to unlucky to choose)..

Comment: Do you have the seaborn module installed too?

Comment: In fact no, I just hadn't thought it would be relevant since I just assumed all the information came inside the matplotlib style library

Comment: I know how to do it with seaborn but I cant seem to get it to work using just matplotlib. I will post an answer that uses seaborn, even though it's not exactly what you asked as it might help someone else that does have the module installed

Comment: You do not need to have seaborn installed to use the `seaborn` style; equally you do not have to have ggplot installed to use the `ggplot` style. Those styles are entirely written in the single .mplstyle file they refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the ticklabels is determined by the `xtick.labelsize` and `ytick.labelsize` rcParams.
If you print them out you see that they are set to `10` (pt) for the `seaborn` style. So if you change them to `18` instead, you will arrive at the desired plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18,
                     'xtick.labelsize' : 18,
                     'ytick.labelsize' : 18})

# ....
```

[image]

As you can see, the axes labels are still tiny. That is because we haven't set the `axes.labelsize` parameter.

So why does `seaborn-dark` work then as expected by simply setting the `'font.size'` only?
The answer is that there are two ways to specify font sizes. One is absolute numbers in points like above, the other is using relative values. Those are `xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large, larger, or smaller`. Those values are relative to the size specified in `font.size`.

In case of the `seaborn-dark` style and (hopefully many others), the `labelsize` is set using one of those relative values. In that case it is `medium` which means that exactly the `font.size` is being used.

You may examine the styles in your `matplotlib\lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib` folder to see directly how they specify the respective parameters and to find out differences between them.